# vba date filter criteria derived from a cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I'm trying to filter data where one filter criteria - month - needs to be entered by the user in a cell on one sheet in the workbook.

If the data is typed into the code, it works fine, as written below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "10/1/2013")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
```

The column to be filtered has dates displayed as `MM-YYYY` but show in the formula bar as `DD-MM-YYYY`. I haven't been able to replace the date `10/1/2013` with a variable, cell ref or named range linked to another sheet.

So, data to be filtered is in `Sheet1` and the month is entered into a cell in `Sheet2`.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: This is quite confusing, to be honest. The way I'm reading this, a user must enter a month, and then the autofilter should only show the dates from that month, am I right? Say, entering `October` or whatever results into all `10/dd/yyyy` dates, yes?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying.  Yes - your correct: The code for the filter is as derived from recorded macro.  The user just selects the month to filter to capture all records for that month, irrespective of day number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VBA to filter my tables but following your example, I believe that you must first:

a). adjust the code to use 2 criterias when filtering. Thus you should capture dates between 1st and 31st. *Your 1st criteria seams to be mixed up*.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<1/10/2013" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">30-10-2013"
```

b). use the mm-yyyy input and build the 2 values that define the timeframe. Do this by adding 1 and 31 to create a valid dates. Then declare the variable:

```
MyMonth = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value 'Change A1 to the cell used to store the month
MyYear = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value 'Change A2 to the cell used to store the year
Month_1st = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth , 1)
Month_31st = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth , 31) 'fine-tuning needed to sort the months ending 30th
' use these in the code above like this:
Criteria1 = "<" & Month_1st
Criteria2 = ">" & Month_31st
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Criteria1  _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=Criteria2
```

Haven't tested this all the way but  I think it should work. I may recommend another approach if the given code is not of use. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this code and sorry for the delay in replying.  I've tried this but I get an error on Month_1st = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth , 1).  The original code was from a recorded macro to filter on month, so I think that format is OK.  Looking at the actual filter in the sheet, selecting a month selects all the day numbers by default, e.g. 1,3,6,16,25.  Do I need a table where selecting a month links to the day range for that month?

Comment: no worry on the delay :), the idea behind the code is to filter the data using two values for month and year (*integers*) **stored in a separate sheet** (in this case in cells A1 and A2 from"sheet2"). This is why I've used `DateSerial`, to transform integer into dates. **These two can be filled either manually or by macros**. To test the code in it's *raw* format either write in "Sheet2" cell A1=8 and A2=2013 or in the code use `MyMonth = 8` and `MyYear = 2013`. Based on this the `Month_1st = 8-1-2013` and `Month_31st = 8-31-2013`. Thus, the filter whould capture whole Aug.2013.

Comment: Thanks Takedasama.  The code runs OK, but returns no results from the filter.  The original macro filters and copies the filtered results to another sheet - the contents of the target sheet are cleared before copy-paste the new results.  With the new code, the target sheet is cleared but doesn't show any results.  I've tried different month numbers.  Do I need a special format for the month and year values?  Or could your code be adapted to fill the date in Criteria2 in my original macro, such as Criteria:=Array(1, & Month_1st)? Your help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: For info, I have found a solution that works well for me:`Dim FilterMonth As Date myYear = Sheets("Menu").Range("C24").Value myMonth = Sheets("Menu").Range("C25").Value FilterMonth = DateSerial(myYear, myMonth, Day(Now))ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P$2173").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _ "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(FilterMonth, "mm/dd/yyyy"))` Hope this is of use to others.